# Undefined Offset Error in a controlled for loop using array_intersect

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting an undefined offset error for the 2 lines I have marked near the bottom of this code. From what I can see it is in a controlled for loop, but obviously something is amiss.

I think that `array_intersect` creates an array of the shared values between `$temparray1` and `$temparray2`.

```
$temparray1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
$temparray2 = (5,5,6,7,8,9);

$array3 = array_intersect($temparray1, $temparray2);

if (!empty($array3)) {
    $match = true;
} else {
    $match = false;
} 

if ($match === true){
    $tempcount = count($array3);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $tempcount){
        //UNDEFINED OFFSET ERROR FOR NEXT 2 LINES
        if(!in_array($array3[$i],$scheduled_groups)){
            $insertgroup = $array3[$i];
            $i++;
        } // End of ifarray
    } // End of while
}
```

Comment: Just a tip... try write the code by chunks (using functions). This will help you understand what's happening.

Comment: Probably the error refers to some position of the array that don't exist. Try use var_dump (in the loop) to see when the php will stop in the error.

Comment: Is it intended that `$i++` is inside the `if`-clause? That would mean that if `array3[$i]` is in `$scheduled_groups` then `$i` would not increment. That can cause an infinite loop because it can happen that `($i < $tempcount)` never holds.

Comment: And also arrays are declared with `[]` not `()`

Comment: ...and missing `;`... Please, paste the real code!